# how to get request body in varnish

Tags: varnish, request

I am currently working on a project based on varnish..

we write vcl and vmod. But the project need check the request body.
Buddies, How can I get request body in VCL or vmod with a C function?
Help Needed.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR;

I think this answer is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12181364/1016425

As mentioned previously by @AndreasM Varnish does not cache POST request by default. But this can be changed if you want.

If you need to cache POST request, this is possible and basically you need to make use of:

```
bodyaccess.hash_req_body();
```

This tutorial has a very good step by step explanation: https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/caching-post-requests/

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381220/varnish-vcl-gurus-how-to-pass-request-body-using-varnish-fetch

Varnish does not operate on POST requests, just passes them through.

Comment: :Hi, andreas, thanks for your reply. Varnish doesnot cache post request, but it matters not much. I need to get the post body in VCL. Do you you know how to realize it?

Comment: I didn't find anything on it. Since varnish doesn't do anything with POSTs except for passing them through, speed is not really of concern here. You could re-route the request to another proxy which CAN work with POSTs, like apache filters or squid.